# Разделение(сортировка) массива по ключам

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть массив продуктов:

```
array(4) {
 [0]=>
  array(21) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(2) "54"
       ...
  ["category"]=>
  string(2) "76"
  ["parent_category"]=>
  string(2) "62"
 }
 [1]=>  
  ...
```

Необходимо их сначала разделить по полю `parent_category`, потом среди тех продуктов у которых совпадают `parent_category` разделить по полю `category`. Т.е. в конечном итоге должно получить что-то подобное:

```
- Родительская категория 1
  -- категория 1
     ~товар из категории 1
     ~товар из категории 1
  -- категория 2
     ~товар из категории 2

- Родительская категория 2
  -- категория 3 
     ~товар из категории 3
  ~товар из родительской категории 3
```

Пока получается их разделить только по родительским категориям

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предположить что исходные такие

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'category' => 1, 'parent_category' => 1],
    ['id' => 2, 'category' => 1, 'parent_category' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'category' => 2, 'parent_category' => 1],
    ['id' => 4, 'category' => 2, 'parent_category' => 1],
    ['id' => 5, 'category' => 3, 'parent_category' => 2],
    ['id' => 6, 'category' => 3, 'parent_category' => 2],
    ['id' => 7, 'category' => 3, 'parent_category' => 2],
    ['id' => 8, 'category' => 3, 'parent_category' => 2],
];

$result = [];
```

> Необходимо их сначала разделить по полю `parent_category`

Ок, давайте так и поступим, вроде не сложно?

```
foreach($data as $d){
    $result[ $d['parent_category'] ] [] = $d;
}
```

> Потом среди тех продуктов у которых совпадают `parent_category` разделить по полю `category`

И повторим аналогично в цикле?

```
foreach($result as &$v){
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($v as $p){
        $tmp[$p['category']][] = $p;
    }
    $v = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за отклик. Но в моем случае данные представлены в виде ` array(21) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(2) "54"
       ...
  ["category"]=>
  string(2) "76"
  ["parent_category"]=>
  string(2) "62"`  можно но ли в этом случае что-нибудь придумать?

Comment: @r.mcreal а что изменилось по сравнению с моими данными?

Comment: А конечный результат в какой переменной хранится?)

Comment: `$result`, очевидно?

Comment: прошу прощения, не сразу понял после вывода. Вроде все работает, спасибо! А не подскажите еще такую вещь, если 'parent_category' == 'category' (т.е. когда товар находится только в родительской категории) он будет выводится только в родительской категории, я все правильно понимаю?

Comment: нет, будет все также два уровня.